# Чтение файла построчно, запись в список

Tags: python, файлы

День добрый! Мне нужно читать файл построчно, и записывать каждую строку в список. (1 элемент в списке - первая строка). Также, в другой список записывать слова (1 элемент - "hello", 2 элемент - "world!")
Как мне это сделать?

Заранее спасибо!

PS: Я знаю, как добавлять элементы в список, (append) проблема в читке построчно, и разделение слов (элементов).

Comment: если ты знаешь как читать построчно и как добавлять в список, то что мешает тебе объединить два этих знания?

Comment: Нда, вопрос переоткрыли, а пользователь, который его задал, уже удалён? Однако )

Comment: @CrazyElf https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12271 модератор сжалился

Answer (score 4):

Разделять строку на слова можно так:

```py
a = "Hello World"
b = a.split()

print(b)
```

Вывод:

```py
["Hello", "World"]
```

А читать файл построчно надо так:

```py
with open("ИМЯ ФАЙЛА") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Добавляем в список строку
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('output.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # readlines() читает файл и добавляет построчно в список
```

Comment: Ну что за дичь, уважаемый. Если не хотите/забываете делать `f.close` просто используйте `with open`. И в `lines` тут будет `None`, ибо нужно сначала присваивать, а потом уже печатать.

Comment: @CrazyElf ай, извините. Я просто скопировал не глядя первое, что в интернете на ридлайнс попалось

Comment: требовалось, во-первых, каждую строку файла добавить в список, во-вторых, каждую строку разбить  на слова и все это запихнуть в другой список. сложно назвать ваш вариант полноценным решением.

Comment: @Dmitry хорошо, пусть будет неполноценное решение!

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, немного странный пример приведен, который не отражает сути вопроса. Обычно "Hello world!" это одна строка.
Если вопрос именно в том, чтобы каждый элемент списка был словом, то, действительно, ответ уже дан (с помощью функции`split()`).
Если же вопрос в том, как читать файл построчно и записывать строки в список, то делает это с помощью цикла `while` и функции `readline()` применяя к файлу. Т.е. вы читаете строки из файла и добавляете их в список, пока у Вас не встретится пустая строка